# Pass post data to a script flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a page that needs to take two arguments which I want to send in a POST request, Login and Password. I keep getting an IndexError: list index out of range from flask, I'm assuming because it is not receiving the arguments for the script.

This is my view.py

```
@app.route("/login/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['login']
        password = request.form['password']
        return redirect(url_for('test', name=name, password=password))
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')


@app.route("/test/", methods=['POST'])
def test():
    name = request.form['login']
    password = request.form['password']
    input = ['/mypath/test.py', name, password]
    a = subprocess.Popen(input, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = a.communicate()
    return out
```

and form

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('test') }}" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="login">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1642, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1743, in make_response
    status=status_or_headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 778, in __init__
    self.status = status
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 886, in _set_status
    self._status_code = int(self._status.split(None, 1)[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you try making an [MCVE] out of this? just a basic test case that reproduces the specific behavior without any extra cruft, no subprocess, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is receiving the POST values just fine; it is returning the response from your view that is the issue here. You are not returning something that [Flask expects to be returned](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#about-responses).

You are returning a *tuple* of strings here:

```
out = a.communicate()
return out
```

because the [`Popen.communicate()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) returns a tuple of `(stdout, stderr)`.

When you return a tuple with two string elements, Flask expects that to be a response body and a *status code*. Since your `stderr` string is *empty*, parsing of the status code (which could be in the form of a `'200 Ok'` or `'404 Not Found'`, etc. form) fails.

Return just the stdout result:

```
stdout, stderr = a.communicate()
return stdout
```

Comment: Thanks! that returned the output of the script!